# why class `d-none` toggles every time when length between two div's is less than 10 while resizing window?

Tags: javascript, html, css

The main goal is to hide the icon when the width of the `right` container and the `rightButtonGroupWrapper` is less than `10` and `show` when `difference` is not less than `10`

what I'm trying to do is show `icons` only if the length between `right container width` and `right button group` is less than `10`. But it starts to toggle every time when I resize the `window`. I'm couldn't figure out what is the problem here?

```js
const props = el => el.getBoundingClientRect();

const right = document.querySelector(".right")
const dropdown = document.querySelector(".dropdown")
const rightButtonGroupWrapper = document.querySelector(".rightButtonGroup");
const allIcons = [...rightButtonGroupWrapper.querySelectorAll("i")];
const allTexts = [...rightButtonGroupWrapper.querySelectorAll(".text-inner")];

function handleWidthChange(e) {
  const rightContainerProps = props(right);
  const rightButtonGroupWrapperProps = props(rightButtonGroupWrapper);

  const rightContainerWidth = rightContainerProps.width;
  const rBtnGrpWidth = rightButtonGroupWrapperProps.width;
  const diff = rightContainerWidth - rBtnGrpWidth;

  if (diff < 10) {
    allIcons.forEach(icon => icon.classList.remove("d-none"));
    allTexts.forEach(text => text.classList.add("d-none"));
  } else {
    allIcons.forEach(icon => icon.classList.add("d-none"));
    allTexts.forEach(text => text.classList.remove("d-none"));
  }
}

window.addEventListener('resize', handleWidthChange, true);
```

```css
.test-container {
  margin-top: 3rem;
  background-color: bisque;
  padding: 0.5rem 0.5rem;
  display: flex;
}

.left {
  display: flex;
  gap: 0.5rem;
}

.right {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  flex: 1;
}

.rightButtonGroup {
  display: flex;
  gap: .5rem;
}

.drop-out {
  background-color: blueviolet;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: white;
  padding: .5rem;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="test-container">

  <div class="left">
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            Dropdown button
          </button>
      <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            Dropdown button
          </button>
      <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="right">
    <span class="rightButtonGroup">
          <a class="drop-out" href="#">
            <i class="d-none fab fa-apple"></i>
            <span class="text-inner">Action</span>
    </a>
    <a class="drop-out" href="#">
      <i class="d-none fab fa-apple"></i>
      <span class="text-inner">Another action</span>
    </a>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">...</button>
      <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    </span>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: When you replace the text with the icon, the width of the element changes, causing there to be more than 10px between the containers on the next resize, which is why element flickers.

Comment: The toggling makes sense. The `resize` event listener is called for every pixel of resizing; the distance is calculated for each pixel. Since `d-none` influences the width, the distance is going to be different for each pixel of resizing.

Comment: @SebastianSimon How to prevent this flickering behavior

Comment: Why you cann't to use *@media* in the css instead of *resize* addEventListener?

Comment: @ЖнецЪ I was doing something different. It is just part of it. I need to solve in this way only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments, the flashing occurs because the system thinks there is room for the texts (when the icons are there) so it puts the texts in, then that shows there wasn't in fact room so it goes back to icons and this gets repeated.

One way of seeing whether there is room for the text versions is to make sure they are the ones with display set at the start of the resize function. Then that function can work out whether there is space or not and then display the right things. There is no flashing because although the display is set and maybe then unset that is all within the one JS function so the screen has not been repainted in between the two settings of display.

```js
const props = el => el.getBoundingClientRect();

const right = document.querySelector(".right")
const dropdown = document.querySelector(".dropdown")
const rightButtonGroupWrapper = document.querySelector(".rightButtonGroup");
const allIcons = [...rightButtonGroupWrapper.querySelectorAll("i")];
const allTexts = [...rightButtonGroupWrapper.querySelectorAll(".text-inner")];

function handleWidthChange(e) {

  // ADDED TO RESET TO HAVE TEXT NOT ICONS SO WE CAN SEE IF THERE IS ROOM FOR THEM NOW
  allIcons.forEach(icon => icon.classList.add("d-none"));
  allTexts.forEach(text => text.classList.remove("d-none"));

  const rightContainerProps = props(right);
  const rightButtonGroupWrapperProps = props(rightButtonGroupWrapper);

  const rightContainerWidth = rightContainerProps.width;
  const rBtnGrpWidth = rightButtonGroupWrapperProps.width;
  const diff = rightContainerWidth - rBtnGrpWidth;

  if (diff < 10) {
    allIcons.forEach(icon => icon.classList.remove("d-none"));
    allTexts.forEach(text => text.classList.add("d-none"));
  } else {
    allIcons.forEach(icon => icon.classList.add("d-none"));
    allTexts.forEach(text => text.classList.remove("d-none"));
  }
}

window.addEventListener('resize', handleWidthChange, true);
```

```css
.test-container {
  margin-top: 3rem;
  background-color: bisque;
  padding: 0.5rem 0.5rem;
  display: flex;
}

.left {
  display: flex;
  gap: 0.5rem;
}

.right {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  flex: 1;
}

.rightButtonGroup {
  display: flex;
  gap: .5rem;
}

.drop-out {
  background-color: blueviolet;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: white;
  padding: .5rem;
  text-decoration: none;
}

</style>
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="test-container">

  <div class="left">
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                Dropdown button
              </button>
      <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                Dropdown button
              </button>
      <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="right">
    <span class="rightButtonGroup">
              <a class="drop-out" href="#">
                <i class="d-none fab fa-apple"></i>
                <span class="text-inner">Action</span>
    </a>
    <a class="drop-out" href="#">
      <i class="d-none fab fa-apple"></i>
      <span class="text-inner">Another action</span>
    </a>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">...</button>
      <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    </span>
  </div>

</div>
```